# Woocommerce age snippet

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets

I uploaded a age snippet for checkout:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'add_birth_date_billing_field', 20, 1 );
function add_birth_date_billing_field($billing_fields) {

    $billing_fields['billing_birth_date'] = array(
        'type'        => 'date',
        'label'       => __('Birth date'),
        'class'       => array('form-row-wide'),
        'priority'    => 25,
        'required'    => true,
        'clear'       => true,
    );
    return $billing_fields;
}
   

     add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_customer', 'save_checkout_account_birthday_field', 10, 2 );
        function save_checkout_account_birthday_field( $customer, $data ){
            if ( isset($_POST['billing_birth_date']) && ! empty($_POST['billing_birth_date']) ) {
                 $customer->update_meta_data( 'billing_birth_date', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_birth_date']) );
            }
        }
```

and it only works if I disable QuadLayers Checkout Fields Manager for WooCommerce but I need it for other fields, does anyone know what I'm wrong? I would like to be able to put the age request (collected data, it is a cultural association, it is used for membership) in a single product (eg id 2201), the plugin does not and I wanted to use a snippet, can someone help me?

and it only works if I disable QuadLayers Checkout Fields Manager for WooCommerce but I need it for other fields, does anyone know what I'm wrong? I would like to be able to put the age request (collected data, it is a cultural association, it is used for membership) in a single product (eg id 2201), the plugin does not and I wanted to use a snippet, can someone help me?
tnx
e.

Comment: Try to increase the priority like `add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'add_birth_date_billing_field', 999, 1 );`

Comment: I wonder why would you use plugin that can create fields but instead go with filter and then use it in the plugin. If you use the plugin just to reorder the fields you can do it with filter too. Pros of doing it with filters is that you will never relay on 3rd party plugin.